# Is there any (specially Algebraic Geometrical) exposition of Koike Terada's Young-diagrammatic methods for the representation theory paper?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, tensor-products, universal-algebra, classical-groups

I am talking about the paper by Koike, Kazuhiko and Terada, Itaru, Young-diagrammatic methods for the representation theory of the classical groups of type ($B_n$), ($C_n$), ($D_n$), J. Algebra 107, 466-511 (1987).

Here, the universal character $\chi_{GL}(\lambda)$ for the general linear group is well understood (For this, see two paragraphs just before Proposition 1.4.2 in that paper).

However, universal characters $\chi_{Sp}(\lambda)$ for the symplectic groups (Definition 2.1.1) are not understood well. Specific question:

i) From where are they getting this $\chi_{Sp}(\lambda)$?

ii) Is there any projective system for Symplectic groups?

iii)This paper has many citations from many backgrounds, like group theory, physics, combinatorics, etc. **I am searching for an exposition of this paper from an algebraic perspective, preferably from the context of algebraic geometry.**